# List all groups from members of a specified group

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I need a group query to get only the groups of members which are part of a certain group.
I found a query for the member list already ([LDAP Query to list all users of a certain group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890049/ldap-query-to-list-all-users-of-a-certain-group)).

But simply changing the **objectCategory** isn't enough.

Is it possible to query the groups of members of a certain group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the filter of `objectCategory=user` to `objectClass=group` but keep the & and the `memberOf=FULL-DN-OF-GROUP-OF-INTEREST`.