# LDAP: Get list of users in a specific group

Tags: java, ldap

I'm trying to get all users of a specific user group. I'm doing this in java, I can connect to ldap and get results from different queries. However I've searched to find solution but as far as I can tell the LDAP of my workplace is structured differently than what seems normal.

dn of users:

```
ou=Users,O=MYCOMPANY.COM
```

dn of the user group:

```
cn=Admin,ou=Profiles,ou=MYAPP,ou=Applirights,O=MYCOMPANY.COM
```

For the user group, cn is the privilege level / group name (Admin) and the name of the application is in an organisational unit. With this structure, how would I query for all users in this specific group?

I tried:

```
NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("ou=Users,O=MYCOMPANY.COM", "(cn=Admin,ou=Profiles,ou=MYAPP,ou=Applirights,O=MYCOMPANY.COM)", searchControls);
```

However what attributes would need to be in search controls? I use `uid` which is the users login name.

I also tried whats outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890049/ldap-query-to-list-all-users-of-a-certain-group):

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=Admin,ou=MYAPP,ou=Applirights,O=MYCOMPANY.COM))
```

Nothing works and with that, I mean I get 0 results but no error. How can I achieve this with the given organisation of ldap?

Answer (score 1):

Groups have something called `memberOf`:
So try this:

```
search -s sub -b "DC=whatever,DC=mydomain,DC=com" "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=GROUP,DC=whatever,DC=mydomain,DC=com))"
```

you fill in `whatever` `mydomain` and `GROUP` above ^

Answer (score 0):

> What attributes would need to be in search controls?

The attributes listed in `searchControls` are the ones you want *returned*. The one containing the group members. Depending on what `objectClass` the group object is, it might be:

- `uniqueMember` for `groupOfUniqueNames`
- `roleOccupant` for `organizationalRole`

and so forth.