# LDAP : Find if user is member of group

Tags: ruby, ldap

Im using the ruby `net/ldap` gem to query against my AD server to get if a user is the member of a group or not and for the life of me cannot figure out where I am going wrong. This is my code (I referenced this answer to come up with the filter - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9890107/1664675):

```
  def query(username)
    result  = nil
    ldap    = Net::LDAP.new(@ldap_settings)   #ldap_settings has the authentication stuff
    filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=#{username})(memberof=CN=group-name,OU=Linux Groups,OU=Linux))"
    if ldap.bind
      ldap.search(:base => @base, :filter => filter) do |object|
        puts object.memberof
        end
    else
      raise 'Authentication Error!'
    end
    result
  end
```

When I call this function as `puts Classname.new.query(username)` it returns nothing.

When I user the filter `filter  = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=#{username}))"` , I can list all the groups the user is part of. Is there any way to just check if the user is part of a group ?

Comment: Is `group-name` the correct DN for the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
def query(username)
    result  = nil
    ldap    = Net::LDAP.new(@ldap_settings)   #ldap_settings has the authentication stuff
    filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=#{username}))"
    if ldap.bind
      ldap.search(:base => @base, :filter => filter) do |object|
        puts object.memberof.include?("CN=group-im-looking-for,OU=myou,OU=ou,DC=dc,DC=dc,DC=dc")
        end
    else
      raise 'Authentication Error!'
    end
    result
  end
```

This returns `True` if user is part of the group else `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct, my suggestion is use the count() method to return the information you want.

```
If count() > 0 then
#is part of group
else
#is not part of group
End if
```

regards