# How to get all the groups for a user from LDAP using person entity in NET::LDAP ruby

Tags: ruby, azure-active-directory, ldap, jruby, netldap

I am using Net::LDAP in ruby to get person entity information like cn,department but I also want the list groups of which the user is member of ,
I tried using memberof attribute but it returns only one group
example given below, but I am memver of multiple groups

```
{:cn=>"Garg, Puja",
 :title=>"Developer",
 :mail=>"Puja@abc.com",
 :samaccountname=>"pujagarg",
 :memberof=>"CN=DEVELOPER TEAM,OU=Distribution Groups,OU=_Global,OU=ABC,DC=int,DC=abc,DC=com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**:memberOf (in AD) is stored as a list of distinguishedNames. Your filter needs to be something like:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=MyCustomGroup,ou=ouOfGroup,dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com))
```

If you don't yet have the distinguished name, you can search for it with:

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=myCustomGroup))
```

Example:

```
filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=#{username})(memberof=CN=group-name,OU=Linux Groups,OU=Linux))"
```

This example list the all the groups the user is part of.

More details refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890049/query-to-list-all-users-of-a-certain-group/9890107#9890107)

**Solution 2**: Example using a modern **ldapsearch** command line tool:

```
ldapsearch --port 1389 --baseDn 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' \
     --sizeLimit 3 --searchScope one --bindDn 'cn=directory manager' \
     --bindPasswordFile ~/.pwdFile '(uid=user.0)' isMemberOf
dn: uid=user.0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=Dynamic Home Directories,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=bellevue,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=shadow entries,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=persons,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

This search response indicated that **user.0** is a member of the listed groups.
The above is a general explanation of one way to deal with group membership from an
LDAP perspective.

Also refer this [link](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches) for more details.